# Grid in Grid table closes on click on Field

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, preventdefault

I use a small grid in a grid to store a relation table.

Example:[grid in grid example](https://dojo.telerik.com/IwImaNax/5)

This works fine so far.

If I now click on the second column in the inner grid table, the whole field with the integrated grid goes out of edit mode. The first field in the inner grid can be edited without problems.

I have tried different types of preventDefault(). But unfortunately no workaround.

What do I have to do so that I can edit the two columns in the inner grid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just changein your editable function

```
editable: true
```

To

```
editable: {
    mode: "inline"
},
```

here is the documentation

https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid/configuration/editable.mode

note that you have **editable:true** twice at your editor: function

Answer (score 0):

runs also with:

```
editable: {
  mode: "popup"
},
```

Similar to the inline mode, edit can be controlled via button.
have fun...

Comment: Although this may be a valid answer, it is good to provide some explanation.